# Retrofit unable to do requests

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have been doing post requests to my localhost server (based on express) and I am using retrofit to post to my PC's IP and both devices (Android and PC are connected through hotspot).
It was working pretty well before but now I have changed my device to a new device running on Android 10 and Now It has stopped working.
And one more thing to notice here is that there are no errors in Logcat and when I go to chrome(Android) and do a GET request it works.

Here is how I am doing a post request

```
        retrofit = retro.getRetrofit();
        Data token = new Data();
        token.setToken("Anything");

        retroInterface service = retrofit.create(retroInterface.class);


        Call<Data> call = service.postToken(token);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
                
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Post done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Here is how I create retrofit object from retro class

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class retro {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.72:3000";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
   if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

   }
   return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Here is my Data class

```
public class Data {
public String token;


public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
}
```

Here is Retrofit interface

```
  import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface retroInterface {
    @POST("/login")
    Call<Data> postToken(@Body Data data );

    @POST("/login")
    Call<username> postUsername(@Body username user);

    @POST("/userAvail")
    Call<username> checkUsername(@Body username user);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to log from onFailure method?

Comment: NicolaGallazzi  It is giving me CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.43.72 not permitted by network security policy

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to it that as I have moved from Android 8 to 10 I need to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
in my manifest file in order to do requests.

Comment: Please remember to remove that line before you publish.

Answer (score 0):

Devil TM has correctly identified that Android 10 devices block plain `http` connections. While adding

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to the manifest will unblock you for continuing development in this scenario, it is very dangerous and there is a risk that it will make it into a published app.

It is better to fix the underlying issue - the unencrypted connection - than to simply tell the app to ignore it and carry on.

This can be achieved in two ways - issuing a self-signed certificate and telling the app to trust your certificate - or getting a real certificate issued. There are many questions and answers on here about how to get the app to trust a self-signed cert and the documentation is  [in the Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl). I'm not going to cover that scenario.

The other way is getting a real certificate. You could of course buy one, but who wants to do that for a development site. I'm assuming that OP is doing 'bedroom development' and all the hassles (no fixed IP, etc) that come with it. To get an encrypted connection, you need to;

- Set up a DYNDNS provider to point at your home IP
- Choose a subdomain of any domain you have and make a `CNAME` record that points to your DNYDNS address
- Set up port forwarding on the router to route `80` and `443` to the server
- Set up the server with a vhost configuration to serve the correct site when the subdomain is requested
- Install and run the `letsencrypt` tool and ask it to issue a certificate for the subdomain on your server

You now have a free real SSL certificate installed and Android will use the connection quite happily.

If you don't want to keep the development server exposed to the Internet all the time, you can remove the port forwards (but will need to set up a `HOSTS` file to map the domain to the server IP). You will only need to expose the server every 3 months, to update your certificate.